# Send attachement as Word document via Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Via Google Spreadsheet I like to send an attachment. The attachment is a Google Doc.

I can sent it as PDF file.getAs('application/PDF') -- however I need it as a Word document (or something that opens up in Word).

It is possible to do send an email manually as Word attachment, however this solution requires to do this automatically.

I tried: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) but that doesn't work.

Kind regards

Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Apps Script can't export anything else than pdf natively but the document API does so you can use urlFetch with parameters to get what you want (don't change these parameters, the request is anonymous and can stay so).

Here is the code, it doesn't require too much explanations except that the urlFetch must be authorized (the process is not the usual one, you'll get a second authorization for this script.)

```
function emailDocTestasDocx() {
  var id = '1I9KIVTLieQbNnmz09zfOBSBNwZ9Tp7B0kfpysaf-ooY';// an example of Google doc
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/';
  var doc = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+'download/documents/Export?exportFormat=doc&format=doc&id='+id,
                              googleOAuth_('docs',url)).getBlob();
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  MailApp.sendEmail(me, 'test', 'see attachment', {attachments:[doc]});
}

function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('anonymous');
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('anonymous');
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

Comment: Thanx Serge. It works, however I like to have the email to be send based on an email address in Google Spreadsheet. When I do this doesn't work (the intended user doesn't get the email). Any ideas for that?

Comment: Did something wrong I think ...it seems to work very nicely, thank you.

Comment: Serge, I tried this code today. It was running smoothly till I think yesterday, but now it won't run. I put a log before and after the var doc line and the logger after doesn't show up in the log. Any ideas what is going on and more importantly how to solve it?

Comment: what does the execution transcript say ?