# Adding doc as attachment in web app

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a web app that that pulls information from a custom form and puts it in a spreadsheet.  The information from the spreadsheet is used along with a document template to do a mail merge, which is then sent as a pdf.  I want to send the file as a word document and not a pdf.  I have already visited [Send attachement as Word document via Google Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044185/send-attachement-as-word-document-via-google-script) and can make it work as a standalone script, but I want to make it work with my web app.  Where do I put that in the code to make it work?  I have tried entering in muliple places and no matter where I put, it makes the web app fail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the code

```
function doGet(e) {
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Bulletin Creator');
var panel = app.createFormPanel();
var grid = app.createGrid(13,2).setId('BulletinGrid');

var bulletinNameLabel = app.createLabel("Bulletin #");
var bulletinTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('bulletin');

var preparedDateLabel = app.createLabel('Date Prepared');
var preparedDateTextbox = app.createDateBox().setWidth('150px').setName('dateprepared');

var releasedDateLabel = app.createLabel('Date Released');
var releasedDateTextbox = app.createDateBox().setWidth('150px').setName('datereleased');

var preparedByLabel = app.createLabel('Prepared By');
var preparedBy = app.createListBox().setWidth('150px').setName('preparedby');
  preparedBy.addItem('Select Option');    
  preparedBy.addItem(', Officer, Intelligence Unit');
  preparedBy.addItem(', Sergeant, Intelligence Unit');  
  preparedBy.addItem('As many');
  preparedBy.addItem('other names');
  preparedBy.addItem('as you need');

var reviewedByLabel = app.createLabel('Reviewed By');
var reviewedBy = app.createListBox().setWidth('150px').setName('reviewedby');
  reviewedBy.addItem('Select Option');    
  reviewedBy.addItem('Officer, Intelligence Unit');
  reviewedBy.addItem('Intelligence Unit');  
  reviewedBy.addItem('As many');
  reviewedBy.addItem('other names');
  reviewedBy.addItem('as you need');

var subjectInterestLabel = app.createLabel('Subject of Interest');
var subjectInterestTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('subjectinterest');

var criminalOffenseLabel = app.createLabel('Criminal Offense');
var criminalOffenseTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('criminaloffense');

var physicalDescriptionLabel = app.createLabel('Physical Description');
var physicalDescriptionParagraphbox = app.createTextArea().setSize('150px', '50px').setName('physicaldescription');

var addressLabel = app.createLabel('Address');
var addressTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('address');

var arrestLocationLabel = app.createLabel('Arrest Location');
var arrestLocationTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('arrestlocation');

var suggestionsLabel = app.createLabel('Suggestions and Recommendations');
var suggestionsParagraphbox = app.createTextArea().setSize('150px', '50px').setName('suggestions'); 

//file upload
var upLoadTypeLabel = app.createLabel('Image Upload'); //Image upload Text
var upLoad = (app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));  //Choose file button

var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>Submit</B>'); //submit button
var warning = app.createHTML('<B>PLEASE WAIT WHILE DATA IS UPLOADING<B>').setStyleAttribute('background','yellow').setVisible(false)

//Grid layout of items on form
grid.setWidget(0, 0, bulletinNameLabel)
  .setWidget(0, 1, bulletinTextbox)
  .setWidget(1, 0, preparedDateLabel)
  .setWidget(1, 1, preparedDateTextbox)
  .setWidget(2, 0, releasedDateLabel)
  .setWidget(2, 1, releasedDateTextbox)
  .setWidget(3, 0, preparedByLabel)
  .setWidget(3, 1, preparedBy)
  .setWidget(4, 0, reviewedByLabel)
  .setWidget(4, 1, reviewedBy)
  .setWidget(5, 0, subjectInterestLabel)
  .setWidget(5, 1, subjectInterestTextbox)
  .setWidget(6, 0, criminalOffenseLabel)
  .setWidget(6, 1, criminalOffenseTextbox)
  .setWidget(7, 0, physicalDescriptionLabel)
  .setWidget(7, 1, physicalDescriptionParagraphbox)
  .setWidget(8, 0, addressLabel)
  .setWidget(8, 1, addressTextbox)
  .setWidget(9, 0, arrestLocationLabel)
  .setWidget(9, 1, arrestLocationTextbox)
  .setWidget(10, 0, suggestionsLabel)
  .setWidget(10, 1, suggestionsParagraphbox)      
  .setWidget(11, 0, upLoadTypeLabel)
  .setWidget(11, 1, upLoad)
  .setWidget(12, 0, submitButton)
  .setWidget(12, 1, warning)

var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(warning).setVisible(true)
submitButton.addClickHandler(cliHandler);  
panel.add(grid);
app.add(panel);
return app;
```

}

```
function doPost(e) {
    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    var bulletin = e.parameter.bulletin; //pass submitted bulletin data through to bulletin variable
    var dateprepared = e.parameter.dateprepared;
    var datereleased = e.parameter.datereleased;
    var preparedby = e.parameter.preparedby;
    var reviewedby = e.parameter.reviewedby;
    var subjectinterest = e.parameter.subjectinterest;
    var criminaloffense = e.parameter.criminaloffense;
    var physicaldescription = e.parameter.physicaldescription;
    var address = e.parameter.address;
    var arrestlocation = e.parameter.arrestlocation;
    var suggestions = e.parameter.suggestions;
    var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile; // data returned is a blob for FileUpload widget  
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getActiveSheet();
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 11).setValues([[bulletin,dateprepared,datereleased,preparedby,reviewedby,subjectinterest,criminaloffense,physicaldescription,address,arrestlocation,suggestions]]);

    var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate).makeCopy(docName + bulletin).getId(); 
    var Doc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);     // Open the new document
    var Body = Doc.getActiveSection();          // Get the document’s body section 
    Body.replaceText('kbulletin', bulletin);
    Body.replaceText('kprepareddate', dateprepared);  
    Body.replaceText('kreleaseddate', datereleased);
    Body.replaceText('kpreparedby', preparedby);
    Body.replaceText('kreviewedby', reviewedby);
    Body.replaceText('ksubjectinterest', subjectinterest);
    Body.replaceText('kcriminaloffense', criminaloffense);
    Body.replaceText('kphysicaldescription', physicaldescription);  
    Body.replaceText('kaddress', address);
    Body.replaceText('karrestlocation', arrestlocation);
    Body.replaceText('ksuggestions', suggestions);

    var totalElements = Doc.getNumChildren();
    var el=[]
    for( var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j ) {
        var element = Doc.getChild(j);
        var type = element.getType();
        if (type =='PARAGRAPH'){
            el[j]=element.getText()
            if(el[j]=='###'){
                element.removeFromParent();// remove the ###
                Doc.insertImage(j, fileBlob).setWidth(150).setHeight(200);// 'image' is the image file as blob 
            }
        }
    }
    Doc.saveAndClose();      // Save and close the temporary document

    var targetfolder = DocsList.getFolderById(bulletinfolderdrop);
    var newfile = DocsList.getFileById(copyId);
    newfile.addToFolder(targetfolder); //Adds file to specified folder
    newfile.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());  //Remove the copy left in the root, leaving only the version in the specific folder

    var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");  //get file as pdf
    var subject = "General Intelligence Bulletin # " + bulletin;    //Email subject  line
    var body = "Attached is bulletin # " + bulletin + " for " + subjectinterest;    //Email Body 

    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: email_address,
    //cc: email_address,
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: body,
    attachments: pdf,});


    var label = app.createLabel('Bulletin # ' + bulletin + ' uploaded successfully');
    app.add(label);

    return app  

}
```

Here is the code that I am trying to incorporate in order to send the attachment as a word document.

```
function emailDocTestasDocx() {
    var id = '1I9KIVTLieQbNnmz09zfOBSBNwZ9Tp7B0kfpysaf-ooY';// an example of Google doc
    var url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/';
    var doc = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+'download/documents/Export?exportFormat=doc&format=doc&id='+id,
                              googleOAuth_('docs',url)).getBlob();
    var me = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
    MailApp.sendEmail(me, 'test', 'see attachment', {attachments:[doc]});
}

function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
    var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
              oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
    oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
    oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
    oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('anonymous');
    oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('anonymous');
    return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

Comment: doGet()and doPost() are invoked whenever a request is made to the script's URL.  Is that what you want/need to trigger your code to run?  Are you putting the code in a `.gs` file?  If you don't want the code to be triggered when the Apps Script URL loads in the web browser, but from the user clicking something, then you need JavaScript code to run Google script.  [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)  If you want a user event to trigger the `.gs` code, then it can't be named `doPost()`, just give it some function name to be called.

Comment: I have created a working web app.  The web app is a form that someone fills out.  As soon as they hit the submit button, it takes the form data, puts it in a spreadsheet and also a word document and sends it to the user as a pdf file.  What I want to happen is the file to be sent to them as a word document as soon as they hit the submit button.  Since I am relatively new at this, pretty much everything you said up top makes no sense to me.  I have tried reading google documentation and have never understood it from the get go.  However, I am good at copying and modifying code for what I need.

Comment: Let's start with the form.  Can you post the HTML for the form?  In your Apps Script editor, some files end with `.html`, and some files end with `.gs`.  The `.gs` files are code that run on Google's servers, not the users computer.  When the user clicks the Submit button, that's from the HTML file, and the users computer.  To get code in the `.gs` file to run on the server, there needs to be a `google.script.run.functionNameInGsFile();` statement.  If there is no `google.script.run.functionName()` statement, then the code won't run.  `doPost()` runs automatically when your app loads.

Comment: I have one script page called bulletin.gs and no html at this point as I have no idea how to do that.  My big goal was to just see what could be done and then go back and try to add to it.

Comment: ok, so is the form a Google Form?  There is something called HTML Service, that can be used to basically build a website with HTML.  I didn't know if you were using that, or just a Google Form.  There needs to be a way to trigger that code to run.  For example, when you run that code, there is an address in the browsers address bar.  You can copy that address, paste it into another browser window, refresh the tab, and the code should run.  Right now, that's one way you can get that code to run, other than manually triggering it from clicking RUN from the code editor.

Comment: I added the doGet part of the script above. Everything is google built as a script.  I do not run the script by clicking the Run button, I published the script as a web app.  I can get the download as a doc to work when running by clicking the run button, but cannot get it to work when placing it in any part of the published web app.  It causes the web app to fail. Here is the link to the web app.  https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxwVFjUDUgJyGLc7GymBqVm_qc2e4Epup58bPC47w0/dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the syntax of how the email is structured:

This is how it should be structured, from the Google Documentation:

```
// Send an email with two attachments: a file from Google Drive (as a PDF) and an HTML file.
 var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
 var blob = Utilities.newBlob('Insert any HTML content here', 'text/html', 'my_document.html');
 MailApp.sendEmail('mike@example.com', 'Attachment example', 'Two files are attached.', {
     name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
     attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF), blob]
 });
```

That example is sending **TWO** attachments.  You only want to send one file.  Note that everything inside the braces `{}` is an object.  The object has two properties, `name:`, and `attachments:`.  The attachments property, has an array for a property value.  An array in JavaScript is inside brackets `[]`.  An array is just a list of elements separated by a comma.

The structure of an array is simple, `[element1, element2, element3, etc]`, but the structure of an object can be a lot more complicated.

To send an email with an attachment, the following syntax must be used:

```
sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)
```

And `options` is an object.  Because it's an object, anything, no matter how simple or complicated, must be enclosed in brackets {}.

To understand an object in JavaScript you can look at this link:  [JSON](http://www.JSON.org)

I'm guessing that the only required advanced parameter is the `attachments` parameter.

Comment: This along with some other things was causing the problem.  Thank you Sandy and also Trash for working with me. Probably learned more about app script in the past week than I have in a couple of months.